# symfony2 form validation and constraint

Tags: symfony, validation

I just created a form that have to "catch" data for transfer them to a "User Object" and persist it to DB.

In order, for do that, i follow those steps:

1. Create a User Object
2. Create a UserRepository for make it persistent and fetch it (throught Entity Manager)
3. Create a class that "map" the form
4. Create a route and a template for render the whole thing

So step over the first two of those and let's see together the third step

```
<?php
namespace Sestante\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\MinLength;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Collection;

class AddUserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function BuildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('username','text')
                ->add('email','email')
                ->add('id','hidden')
                ->add('password','text')
                ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'AddUser';
    }
```

This is part of the class that i've created for "form handle".
Obviously i want to add some kind of validation to my form, and following [symfony2 book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html) i've done this

```
public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    $collectionConstraint = new Collection(array(
        'username'=> new MinLength(4),
        'email'=>new Email(array('message'=>'invalid email address')),
    ));

    return array(
        'data_class' => 'Sestante\UserBundle\Entity\User',
        'validation_constraint' => $collectionConstraint
    );
}
```

As far i understood, constraints will be checked on the `$form->bindRequest(...)` or `->bind(...)` calls.

So, into my controller, i've done this

```
public function insertAction(Request $request)
{
   if($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){
       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
       $user = $em->getRepository('SestanteUserBundle:User');
       $userObj = new User();
       $userObj->setSalt('prova');
       $parameters = $request->request->get('AddUser');
       $parameters['password'] = sha1($parameters['password']);
       $userObj->setGroups($em->getRepository('SestanteUserBundle:Groups')->find(3));
       $form = $this->createForm(new AddUserType(), $userObj);
       $logger = $this->get('logger');
       $logger->info('PROVA: '.gettype($parameters));
       $form->bind($parameters); /* al posto che fare un bind della form, faccio un bind normale con i parametri presi dalla post e modificati
                                 vedi la password che deve subire uno sha1 */
       $em->persist($userObj);
       $em->flush();
       return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('SestanteUserBundle_homepage'));
   }
```

But as i submit the form, i'll have to struggle with this error

> Expected argument of type array or Traversable and ArrayAccess, object
>   given

The strangest thing is that the only two object involved in this operation (bind argument and constraint collections) are of requested type.
So i don't know how to overtake this.
Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with something like this:

```
public function insertAction(Request $request)
{
    // First: Create you're object with only what you need
    $userObj = new User();

    // Then, build you're form
    $form = $this->createForm(new AddUserType(), $userObj);

    // Form submitted?
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        // Bind $request now !
        $form->bindRequest($request);

        // Your object is updated (not saved, ofc). You can now do what you want.
        $userObj->setPassword(sha1($user->getPassword());
        $userObj->setGroups($em->getRepository('SestanteUserBundle:Groups')->find(3));

        // Finish, save user
        $em->persist($userObj);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('SestanteUserBundle_homepage'));
    }
}
```

Some other things:

- you don't need to put the id field in your form.
- you should probably take a look at the sf2 security. It's not a good idea to manually encode 
  password in a controller.

**Edit:**

You got this Exception because you can't use the `validation_constraint` option in a form which deal with an object.

This option can only be used with an array of data.

Comment: About "manually encode in a controller" i follow that [page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#book-security-encoding-user-password) that say "encode user password directly into controller". So, what's the alternative and why symfony's developer that wrote that cookbook says different? 
However, i'm changing my code to try your answer

Comment: Concerning password encoding, you directly use sha1 method. In the cookbook, an encoder is called.
Concerning your problem, can you paste the stacktrace somewhere?
If you remove the validation_constraint, does the form work correctly?

Comment: Yes, if I remove the validation_constraint is all good. Either method: mine and yours.

Comment: And what's the difference between calling and encoder and do the encoding directly into controller?

Comment: I'm so stupid... You can't use the `validation_constraint` option in a form which edit... an object. It's works only with an array.

Comment: I suppose that you're wrong... That's because reading the book, there is an example where `validation_constraint` are used with a class that is obviously mapped to an object. If you have the book (that you can retrive at this [url](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html) take a look to pages 149-150

Comment: The Form class is used to build Form. The Encoder is used to encode password. The controller is used to control them. If one day you need to encode a password in a cli command for example, you can call the resolver instead of have 2 times the same logic. The sha1 is probably not the better example, I agree... ;)

Comment: In the book, pages 149-150, you have the section called: Using a Form WITHOUT a Class. :)

Comment: read the last line onto page 149: 
"If you're using a form class, override the getDefaultOptions method to specify the option:"

Comment: Yes, a form class. But with an array of data, not an entity. Form class can be used with an object or with an array. And the `validation_constraint` option can only be used with an array of datas...

Comment: Umh, ok... But from the book this isn't easy to understand.
So, have I to define those constraints elsewhere like into class (object) itself via annotation (that have to be activated) or some file.yml ? And also, have I to call isValid() mathod?
Am I telling right?

Comment: Meanwhile, +1 for effort and answers details

Comment: Look the [dedicated chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html). You can use annotations or yml.
And you don't need to call the isValid method, the FormComponent do it for you. :)

Comment: Now it's a little bit mor clear. Thank you for your time and patience :)